# string index out of range error at end of for loop

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying to find longest common prefix among all the strings in the list strs

```py
def longestCommon(strs : list):
    long_comm = strs[0]
    for i in strs:
        print(min(len(i), len(long_comm)))
        for j in range(min(len(i), len(long_comm))):
            print(j)
            if i[j] != long_comm[j]:
                long_comm = long_comm[:j]
            
        print(long_comm)

        
longestCommon(["flight", "flow", "flood"])
```

this results in string index out of range error

the output is -

```
6 # this is value of min(len(i), len(long_comm))
0 # these are value of j for 0th element of strs
1
2
3
4
5
flight
4 # this is value of min(len(i), len(long_comm)) for 1st element of strs
0
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\timer.py", line 13, in <module>
    longestCommon(["flight", "flow", "flood"])
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\timer.py", line 7, in longestCommon
    if i[j] != long_comm[j]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

the value of j should only go upto 3 in the second loop and length of 1st element is 4

Comment: what is your desire output ?

Comment: im trying to find longest common prefix, its a leetcode problem, there are alternative solutions too but im trying to see if my method works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a new var to store the updated `long_comm` string,then assign it to `long_comm` after the loop is completed, check this out :

```
def longestCommon(strs: list):
    long_comm = strs[0]
    for i in strs:
        print(min(len(i), len(long_comm)))
        updated_long_comm = ""
        for j in range(min(len(i), len(long_comm))):
            print(j)
            if i[j] != long_comm[j]:
                break
            updated_long_comm += i[j]
        long_comm = updated_long_comm
        print(long_comm)

longestCommon(["flight", "flow", "flood"])
```

result :

```
6
0
1
2
3
4
5
flight
4
0
1
2
3
flow
3
0
1
2
flo
```

good luck !

Comment: ohh i get it now, i think it was because i was concatenating the string i was looping through thats why i was getting index error

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in range(...):` loops in python only execute the `range(...)` part once, just before the loop starts for the first time. This produces an iterable which python just remembers, and checks each value in that iterable. This is different from some other languages, which check the condition at the start of each iteration.

In your case, `range(min(len(i), len(long_comm)))` in your for loop will only execute once at the start of the loop, and will make a list of numbers up to the `min(len(i), len(long_comm))` *at that moment*. But the first time your `if` is activated, the length of `long_comm` decreases. Then, the next iteration of the loop, `j` is one more than the length, and so checking `long_comm[j]` gives you an IndexError.

The other answer is one way to fix this (adding another variable to hold the `updated_long_comm`, and only updating it after the loop finishes). Another might be using a `while` loop instead so that the condition is checked on each iteration.

```
def longestCommon(strs : list):
    long_comm = strs[0]
    for i in strs:
        print(min(len(i), len(long_comm)))
        j = 0                                    # initialize
        while j < min(len(i), len(long_comm)):   # check condition
            print(j)
            if i[j] != long_comm[j]:
                long_comm = long_comm[:j]
            j += 1                               # increment
           
        print(long_comm)
```